# How to reach global window variables from async self executing functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, self-executing-function

How can I set window variables from inner side of async self excuting function. When I use await just before fetch, I get "error: Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined". When I removed the await, in that case, I get the Promise object.

```
(async function (w){

    bar = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(()=>{
      response.json()
    }).then((data)=>{
      return data
    });

    w.bar=bar;

 })(window); 

 console.log(bar);
```

Comment: because it's async function

Comment: You're assigning to the global variable just fine. Put it's pointless, as the code outside of the async IIFE does not wait until the variable is assigned. So don't make it global, and put the `console.log` *inside* the async function, after the `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error: Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined` is being throw at the time you try to log `bar` `console.log(bar);`

This cannot work since your are waiting for the fetch to complete using `await` keyword, so the when this line `console.log(bar);` is reach your variable `bar` is not defiend because the `fetch()` did not finish yet and this line `w.bar=bar;` was not called yet.

If you need to use the result of your fetch outside of the function, remove `await` keyword and whereever you need to use the the result wait for the promise to complete, for example to log it: `bar.then(data => console.log(data))`